# select N-1 records for update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I want to update n-1 records from result set. Can this be done without loops?

If my query is like this:

```
with cte(id, count)
as
(
  select e.id, count(*) as count
  from data
  where id in (multiple values)
  group by id
  having count(*) >1
)
```

Now I want to update the rows in another table with the resulting id's but only any n-1 rows for each `id` value from the above query. Something like this:

```
update top( count-1 or n-1) from data2
inner join cte on data2.id = cte.id
set somecolumn = 'some value'
where id in (select id from cte)
```

The `id` column is not unique. There are multiple rows with the same `id` values in table data 2.

Comment: What does `n` correspond to? You should probably provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: the id column. There are multiple rows with similar id's. I only want n-1 of these rows for each id to be modified.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear whether n is the count of ID in table [data], or the count of that ID in table [data2].  One way or another you'll need to use ROW_NUMBER(), but let's be clear exactly what table contains the count of ID that you intend to use as 'n'.  From there, it'll be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you all. Nick is right. I had to use row_number() with partition and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It uses two CTEs; the first generates the list of eligible `id` values to update, and the second generates row numbers for `id` values in `data2` which match those in the first CTE. The second CTE is then updated if the row number is greater than 1 (so only `n-1` rows get updated):

```
with cte(id, count) as (
  select id, count(*) as count
  from data
  where id in (2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
  group by id
  having count(*) >1
),
cte2 as (
  select d.id, d.somecolumn,
         row_number() over (partition by d.id order by rand()) as rn
  from data2 d
  join cte on cte.id = d.id
)
update cte2
set somecolumn = 'some value'
where rn > 1
```

Note I've chosen to order row numbers randomly, you might have some other scheme for deciding which `n-1` values you want to update (e.g. ordered by `id`, or ...).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? The `CTE` identifies ALL of the source rows, but the `WHERE`clause in the `UPDATE` statement limits the updates to *n*-1.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RowNum
  FROM data
)
UPDATE t
 SET t.<whatever> = <whateverElse>
FROM 
 otherTable AS t
 JOIN 
 cte AS c
  ON t.id = c.id
WHERE
 c.RowNum > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to slightly modify your query and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work just fine

```
;with cte(id, count)
as
(
select e.id, count(*) as count
from data
where id in (multiple values)
group by id
having count(*) >1
)
update data
set soemcolumn = 'some value'
from data join cte on cte.id = data.id
;
```